# Shortcut on Mac: auto google a word/phrase in new window

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, search

When doing research, for example, this shortcut is a big help.

You highlight a word or phrase on a webpage [then hold down the shortcut keys + hit spacebar, I think
] and it will open a new page with a google search in a new window.

I've seen this done. But I don't know what keys to hold down for the shortcut.

Comment: What browser? Google Chrome or Safari. If Google Chrome, I assume there about a hundred different extensions that can get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

In Safari, it should be on the right-click menu.

Select your text, right click...

[image]

1st option is a Dictionary lookup, 2nd is whichever search engine is selected in Safari prefs.

It also works in some, but not all, other apps - I presume the ones that follow the Apple guidelines most closely.

It's also available as a key-commandable Service
System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services
I found I had to change the default, as it conflicted with 'Show Sidebar' in Safari

[image]